# Angular youtube-embed error when passing a variable in ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have installed this [youtube-embed package](https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed) in order to do manipulate elements on my page on player events. In my app I am listing articles with `ng-repeat` so I need to pass the video url as a variable to the directive. Since on the package github page it is described that you should pass a `$scope variable` name as a string to the directive in order to display a video, since I can't pass it as a scope variable, I wonder if I can pass it in ng-repeat?
Because when I do it like this I get an error:

```
<youtube-video video-url="{{article.external_media[0].original_url}}"></youtube-video>
```

> ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{'
>   invalid key at column 2 of the expression
>   [{{article.external_media[0].original_url}}] starting at
>   [{article.external_media[0].original_url}}].

Comment: does it work if you pass it without the interpolation symbols (i.e. remove the `{{ }}`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<youtube-video video-url="linkVariable"></youtube-video>
<youtube-video video-url="'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSdKmX2BH7o'"></youtube-video>
```